# How to Listen Value Change in Primitive Data Type (in this case: boolean)

Tags: java, android, listener

I want to make some code which its execution is triggered by value change of a boolean in my Android project. does that means creating a listener? Would you mind showing a sample to me?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything of your application, I will suggest an implementation of the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). There are examples for a Java implementation on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: that is exactly what I need. Sorry about my application code's devoid. I not yet develop it. Just want to learn this case before developing. Thank's a lot for your answer.